# Qui and its uses

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-interrogatifs

My French teacher recently told me that the interrogative *qui* can be used both as an interrogate as well as taking the place of a pronoun. I may be incorrectly interpreting what she said and this may not actually be the two usages of *qui*. I just remember that she said it functioned differently than other interrogatives; why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Qui* IS a pronoun : It can play the same role as a noun in a sentence.

It can be use for interrogating or as a *pronom relatif* that describes a noun. It is used to replace a person (and sometimes an animal too). It is thus similar to "who"(or sometimes the old "whom"). In a question, "qui" is the unknown part of the sentence. You expect that the answer will replace "qui" with a noun (e.g. the name of the person who is knocking on the door.

example

*Pronom interrogatif*:

> Qui frappe à la porte ?

*Pronom relatif*:

> La personne qui frappe à la porte semble pressée.

Note that *qui* is here the subject of *frapper*, but it can also play other roles in the sentence e.g.

> A qui parlais-tu ?
>   Qui as-tu invité à ton anniversaire ?

However, as a *pronom relatif*, il will no more be used as a *complément d'objet direct*. You must use *que* instead.

> La personne quE tu as invitée à ton anniversaire m'a confirmé sa venue.

Comment: Why does qui replace a noun in a sentence?

Comment: @MorellaAlmann It has the same behavior than "*who*". You can say "*who* is it ?" or "The person *who* talks"